Ошибка определения {invoke} при разработке приложения в Rust с использованием библиотеки Touri и Vite с React, TypeScript + SVG Framework
Я использую Tauri в своем проекте React, и после настройки всех необходимых библиотек я столкнулся с ошибкой при попытке использовать функцию invoke из модуля @tauri-apps/api. Ошибка гласит:
Module "@tauri-apps/api" has no exported member "invoke".
Несмотря на то, что я установил все необходимые зависимости (например, @tauri-apps/api и @tauri-apps/cli), функция invoke не распознается и вызывает ошибку в браузере. Вот мой package.json:
{
  "name": "bondify-client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc -b && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "tauri": "tauri"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tauri-apps/api": "^2.0.2",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.11.1",
    "@tauri-apps/cli": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^22.7.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^9.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.12",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.7.0",
    "vite": "^5.4.8"
  }
}

Here is tsx code:
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.tsx';
import './index.css';
// When using the Tauri API npm package:
import { invoke } from '@tauri-apps/api';


invoke('greet', { name: 'World' })
  // `invoke` returns a Promise
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
)

Я использую Node.js версии 20.x. В чем может быть причина того, что invoke не распознается?
Я уже пробовал воссоздать проект с нуля и следовал официальным инструкциям Tauri, но проблема осталась.
